# Cannot add image asp.net mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model of Client with a property — public string PhotoPath {get; set;}.

I'm trying to add an image in Create httppost method:

```
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase file, Guid id)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            string pic = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            string path = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                                   Server.MapPath("~/images/profile"), pic);
            file.SaveAs(path);
            Client client = db.Clients.Find(id);
            if (client == null) return HttpNotFound();
            client.PhotoPath = path;
            ViewBag.IMAGEPATH = path;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }
```

There is a view (with buttons for adding):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "ClientsController", FormMethod.Post,
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = Model.СlientIdentificator }))
    {
        <label for="file">Upload Image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="width: 100%;" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="submit" />
    }
```

But then I'm trying to upload an image there is no any result (image doesn't upload) or there is an exception targeted to id = Model.ClientIdentificator: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqA4y.png

As a result, I'm really want to ask you for universal method to upload an image for client, using controller's method with two arguments HttpPostedFile file and Guid cliendId or a method that is compatible for my task.

P.S. I'll be extremely thankful
P.P.S. Sorry for my English skills :3)

Comment: Would you mind translating the exception word for word on the image?

Comment: I'm so sorry.

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of the object. (It is targeted to id = Model.ClientIdentificator argument)

Comment: It looks like 'Model.ClientIdentificator' is null. On the GET action for that view, make sure that isn't null. Also, you'll want to add 'db.SaveChanges()' before your return statement.

Comment: In your POST method you are initializing a `Client`, setting its `PhotoPath` property and also setting a `ViewBag` property, all of which are pointless because you then just redirect to another method so both are disposed and never used. As @johnnyRose, indicated, perhaps you need to call `db.SaveChanges();` to save the `Client` and its `PhotoPath` property? In any case, you can delete `ViewBag.IMAGEPATH = path;`- its does nothing. The reason for the error should be self explanatory - your have not set the value of `СlientIdentificator` so its null.